# Access SQL database - ORDER BY

Tags: sql, ms-access, jet

I'm using an MRP system for stocking inventory where I work. The interface it self isn't the best, so I have decided to open up the database file and do everything manually. I'm having some issues though. I'm trying to sort my database by using `ORDER BY`. I'm not getting the results I thought I would. It is showing them in this format:

```
1
10
100
101
101
11
110
111
```

etc

Instead of

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

etc

This is my query

```
SELECT * 
    FROM tblStockItems
    Order By (`MasterPNo`)
```

I'm currently working in access, and then database is in the JET format. If you're wondering why I am using access instead of the MRP Interface, it is because later down the line I will be needing to re-organise the whole stock system, so a lot of fields will have their product numbers changed.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if possible, change the column type to number

if not, a cast should do it:

```
ORDER BY Val(MasterPNo)
```

Comment: That isn't possible, I have assemblies which use letters.

Comment: try to cast the MasterPNo column to Integer or Long via CInt or CLng. Your order by clause will look then like ORDER BY CInt(`MasterPNo`)

Comment: then try using ORDER BY Val(MasterPNo)

Comment: There we go. Thank you. Would you like to put that as an answer and then I can accept it? Thanks again